# What is the meaning of " better utilise data for.."?

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

[From this article](https://www.thedrum.com/news/2019/03/29/ms-appoints-odd-clothing-and-home-agency-restore-its-style-credentials)

> Together, we’ll be looking to build on early successes with our digital-first approach to campaigns including ‘Holly’s Must Haves’ ***and to better utilise data for ‘always on’ cross-channel campaigns.***

I don't understand the meaning of the bold part. What's the meaning of **to better utilise data for..**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"to better utilise data" means "to use data more effectively/efficiently".

> Nathan Ansell said the brand needed "more targeted, inspirational and relevant customer marketing" to restore its style credentials.

M&S gathers information about their customers and, in order to become more successful, they need to process the data they are collecting more thoughtfully and more thoroughly.

*To utilise* (utilize, AmE) *something* is *to use it*, *to employ it*, *to make use of it*.

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/utilize?q=utilise

Comment: Your answer was flagged as a possible low quality post because of it's brevity. Can you add anything more to help the OP understand the bold part of the sentence and how it relates to the rest of the sentence. Your answer is factually correct but there's a lot more that could be written to help this person move forward as an English speaker.

Comment: @dwilli I was going to but got distracted... Updated.

Comment: Sorry but where is it being said that M&S gathers information about their customers?

Comment: To add to the previous comment, the definition of *utilize* you give makes no mention of *more effectively/efficiently*. You seem to be adding those synonyms without supporting evidence. The only thing you can conclude (from the definition you gave) is that *better utilize* means *use, employ, or make use of better*.

Comment: @JasonBassford my dictionary says "to utilise" is "to use something in an effective way", so "effectively" makes sense, doesn't it?

Comment: @AllyFe Actually, I don't know where their data is coming from. I assumed they've got it from customers because it's pretty common for retail companies...

Comment: @AndrewTobilko I went by the seeming definition that you provided in your answer in the final sentence. If your dictionary actually mentions *effective*, then that should be part of the definition that you put in italics. (Or the actual definition should be quoted.)